How to delay beginning of audio without re-encoding?
I have a file containing both video and audio stream. I want to delay the audio by 5 seconds relative to the beginning of the video, without having to do any re-encoding.
The command I tried was:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -itsoffset 5 -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output.mp4

But it doesn't seem to have any effect.
Interestingly enough, the opposite shift, advancing audio by 5 seconds, works fine:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -itsoffset -5 -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output.mp4

What could be the reason for this behavior? What do I need to change?

Depends on player.

You're writing that VLC player should honor the delay, but VLC player is what I'm using. Also, is there no way to "edit" the "timestamps" in-place? Or to permanently apply the editlist?

If 'advancing' works, does it work for the video stream? Same effect as retarding the audio, if so.
